# Geometric argument to solve $|x-1|<|x+1|$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I am trying to solve the inequality
$$|x-1|<|x+1|$$
using geometry. In general, I know that $|x-c|$ for $x,c\in\mathbb{R}$ can be thought of as the distance from $x$ to $c$. This is easy to view on a number line. However, I am unsure of how to solve the problem at hand using a similar argument. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Use the distance interpretation: which numbers $x$ are closer to 1 than -1?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio All numbers $x>0$?

Comment: Good, that's your answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this was originally answered in comment form, but to cut down on the number of unanswered questions, I'll answer now. The inequality means that the distance between $x$ and $1$ is less than the distance between $x$ and $-1$. You've correctly concluded that this is equivalent to the inequality $x>0$.